# 12V Lithium Ion Polymer Battery

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I am trying to develop a product that requires a 12 V portable rechargeable battery that can output at least 2 A. Since conventional LiPo battery runs only on 3.7 nominal voltage, is it advisable to series-connect 3-4 of these batteries to achieve 12 V? What chip should I use to charge the battery?

Comment: "I am trying to develop a product that requires a 12 V portable rechargeable battery" - no battery puts out exactly 12V over its entire discharge and at all currents (a '12V' lead acid battery is fully charged at 13.8V, and may go as low as 10.5V under load). What range of voltages does your product work on?

Comment: I am trying to run both a thermoelectric module and a 12V DC fan. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax7HM_d6jDY. My design requires incorporation of a portable rechargeable battery. Can you help me verify its voltage requirements? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on limited info, either a 12V lead acid, or 3S Lipo "RC Style" battery, or even 10 NiMH batteries in series would work fine.